# Java SAXParser - keep InputStream open

Tags: java, stream, sax

I've a `BufferedInputStream` from which I want to parse XML with `SAXParser` but then reuse it again (eg. `mark(int)` & `reset()`). However this stream is closed in `parse()` method. Is it possible to somehow tell `SAXParser` to leave it open? The last resort is to wrap this stream with un-closeable stream.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class WontCloseBufferedInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {
  public void close () {
    // Do nothing.
  }

  public void reallyClose() {
    super.close ();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am interested to know why you see this as a last resort. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Because it's ugly. IMO library shouldn't close passed in InputStream/Reader.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass **InputSource object rather than InputStream** object to SAXParser

**sample code**

```
SAXParser parser = // saxpaser object
        InputSource isource = new InputSource();
        InputStream istream = //your inputstream
        isource.setByteStream(istream);
        parser.parse(isource, handler);
```

Comment: Is the `InputSource` closed when the parser completes? If so this is unhelpful.

Comment: But then this post doesn't solve the problem neither hints the solution :o)